# Dealing with questions in Low Quality Posts queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In the Low Quality Posts queue what should I do with this question?

[image]

Someone has already provided a good comment, which I upvoted.

Is it just best to select 'Looks OK' because the comment has done the job?

I don't want to 'Recommend Close', and there is not enough to go on to provide an 'Edit'. In the past I have usually gone to 'Skip' but then it just passes it onto someone else.

I had a look on Meta, and GIS Meta but I didn't find any clear guidance on this.

Comment: If you don't want to Recommend closure, then you could downvote it.  Why do you not recommend closure?

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't hurt to add another comment asking for more info.  Sometimes comments from different people worded differently can help the asker understand what their question was lacking.

Comment: I would upvote the comment on that question too, but what job has the comment done?  Has it already led to the asker improving their question?  If not, then I don't think you should ever click "Looks OK" unless you think it already meets the site quality standards.

Comment: Before I upvoted your question I had a quandary about whether to do so because that might be misinterpreted as me seeing any case for choosing "Looks OK" - I think that would be the worst of your four choices unless you think that it should never have reached the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example question given can now only be seen, by those who can see deleted questions, at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261498, because it was self-deleted by its asker, after accumulating its fourth close vote of "unclear what you're asking".

Personally, I would have voted to close this question as too broad.  However, if the question had been more focused as:

> Is there a way to create a hexagonal pyramid in QGIS?

then my approach would be different.

My first thought would be "I know what they are asking, and they are asking a single question, but there is nothing to show that they have tried even a Google search before asking".

With that thought, I think about the first part of the guidance provided by the downvote's tooltip which is:

> This question does not show any research effort

and so I would apply a downvote (by visiting the question, if necessary), and try to find time to also make a comment to ask what they have tried.

- I would not choose OK because the question shows no research effort.
- I would not Edit, because the main thing missing from this question, after reducing its scope to asking about a single product, is knowing what the asker has tried, and only they can provide that.
- I would not Recommend Close, unless it was still asking about two products (i.e. two questions, and then my reason would be Too Broad)
- I would choose Skip

By the time the next reviewer sees the question, I would hope that the asker has addressed my comment and downvote, by providing some details of their research, and if not, then I think a reasonable action by the next reviewer would be to upvote my comment (or make another), downvote the question, and choose Skip too.